# Why Do I Get Artifacting In Photoshop Artboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop, visual-artifacts

I get this wicked magenta and black artifacting when in Photoshop CS4 on Mac when I resize the window.  It doesn't affect the image canvas, but it's on the artboard all around it.

Hardware:

- Early 2008 Macbook Pro
- OS X 10.5
- 4GB RAM
- GeForce 8600M GT (512MB video RAM)

[image]

Comment: Weird. Which hardware/software do you have specifically?

Comment: Nothing really special or unusual.  Early 2008 Macbook Pro running OS 10.5, 4GB RAM, 512MB Video RAM, GeForce 8600M GT.  Photoshop CS4.

Comment: I'd check my video card drivers, if I were you. If it starts happening in other programs then your graphics card might be on its way out... A weird bug, to be sure :-/

Comment: Photoshop is the only program that this happens in, and if I hide PS and then unhide it again, it's gone.  It's happened since I installed PS 2 years ago.  Not a showstopper, but an inconvenience since I depend on the gray background for contrast.

Comment: And it doesn't happen all the time.  I can't pinpoint any commonalities between occurrences.  Tumbleweed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug between Photoshop and your graphics card drivers. If you're still seeing problems with the latest nVidia driver, you can reduce the amount of hardware acceleration in Photoshop. This should stop these issues.